# Doesn't a metric on a set always induce a quasi-order relation?

Tags: metric-spaces, order-theory

Given that we define a metric on a set **A**, each element of the set has a certain distance from another element.
Let's say we choose a particular element of the set and we form the equivalence classes of the elements that have the same distance from the particular element.
To each eqivalence class will then correspond a real number. This gives us a  sort of order/classification that at least provide us for a way to organize our set.
In fact, it only  doesn't match the antisimmetry axiom for orderded sets, but I read somewhere that this kind of relation is called a  quasi-order or pre-order relation.
I'm just approaching these subjects, so I'm not sure that this will always be the case or if my reasoning is completely mistakem

Comment: Yes, it does. In my experience the term "pre-order" is much more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right: the relation that you defined *is* a preorder. And it induces an order relation in the equivalence classes.